# Task finished with error - code: -999 ios playing video with avplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avkit

I want to make a demo app that plays video loaded from the network just with following sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ftp.cp.108tian.com/video/unity_animation.mov"];
    AVPlayer *avp = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url];

    AVPlayerViewController *avpc = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    avpc.player = avp;

    [self presentViewController:avpc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And yes, I have added the `AST` to allow HTTP transmission:

[image]

But I still get this error:

[image]

What happened? and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`Present` should be in `viewDidAppear`/`viewWillAppear` in addition to a valid url

```
[self presentViewController:avpc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: still the same error code -999 after moving the code to `viewDidAppear` and I have tried the other [online source](https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4) for this to make sure the video file is ok